# Как правильно хранить данные для теста?

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Привет всем!

Хочу написать тест наподобие этого:
https://mezoestetic.ru/mezotest/

Решила начать с нуля, но столкнулась с вопросами, которые не знаю как решить (т.к. сама еще 0 во всем этом). 
Вот наработка:
https://codepen.io/anavozhko/pen/WOVvxr

Сейчас это все хранится вот так:

```
const myQuestions = [
        {
            parent: 0,
            id: 1,
            question:
                "Пройдите тест и узнайте, какой мезороллер и косметика подойдут Вам",
            answers: {
                1: "Волосы",
                2: "Глаза"
            }
        }, //...
```

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать где и в каком виде лучше хранить данные для этого теста (особенно результаты в виде html-кода)? Я понимаю, что хранить все в скрипте - это не хорошо. Может хранить это все в базе и как-то ajax-ом доставать? И, вообще, в правильную ли сторону я движусь? Может нужно делать все по-другому?

P.S.: Прошу, не судите строго. Я первый раз разбираюсь в js.

Comment: Конечно лучше продумать структуру таблицы (или таблиц) в БД и хранить вопросы и ответы в них. Так же создать php файл (или файлы) в которые будете ajax-ом стучаться, получать данные и выкидывать ответ пользователю

Comment: каждый тест можно хранить в `json` и дергать `ajax`'ом в зависимости от выбора пользователя

Comment: @al-mr Спасибо, буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: @webDev_ Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Таблица questions:
id (int A_I),
questionText (text),

Таблица answerVariants
id (int A_I),
questionId (int), номер вопроса к которому этот вариант ответа
answerText (text),

Потом в файл провайдер для аякс запроса:

```
//(Using PDO)
$question = DataBase::fetchColumn("SELECT questionText FROM questions WHERE id = :id", ['id' => $id]));
$answers = DataBase::fetchAll("SELECT id,answerText FROM answers WHERE questionId = :questionId", ['questionId' => $id]);
echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'question' => $question, 'answers' => $answers]);
```

итого в ответ получим что-то типа:

```
(jsonObject)

{
    'success': true, 
    'question': "Мой вопрос номер 1?", 
    'answers': [
        ['id': 1, 'answerText' => "Ответ 1"], 
        ['id': 2, 'answerText' => "Ответ 2"]
    ]
}
```

Ну и потом для AJAX вывода.

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function (questionObject) {
    if(questionObject.success === true) {
        $('#questionText').text(questionObject.question);
        $('#answersListUl').html("");
        (questionObject.answers).forEach(function (answerObject) {
            $('#answersListUl').append("<li id='answerId_" + answerObject.id"'>" + answerObject.answerText + "</li>");
        });
    }
}
```